# Transform a triangle on a plane

Tags: geometry, transformation, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

There is a triangle with points `P1(x1,y1)`,`P2(x2,y2)`,`P3(x3,y3)` on an XY plane.

The final position after transformation are known to us, `P1'(x,y)` and `P2'(x,y)`
How can I find the third point?

Using slope (or distance) formula gives two solutions (one is mirror image of another). Assuming the transformation is a combination of translation and rotation, how do I get the new coordinates of the final point `P3'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have got solution using distance formula, you need only to choose what mirror point is needed. To clarify, find sign of cross product of `P1P2` vector and `P1P3` vector. Then find sign of cross product of of `P1'P2'` vector and `P1'Px` vector. If signs differ, get another point.

```
CrossProduct = (P2.X - P1.X) * (P3.Y - P1.Y) - (P2.Y - P1.Y) * (P3.X - P1.X)
```

In general case you can find transformation matrix coefficients and apply this matrix to the third point

```
     c  -s  0
M =  s   c  0
     dx  dy 1
```

equation system

```
c * x1 + s * y1 + dx = x1' 
-s * x1 + c * y1 + dy = y1' 
c * x2 + s * y2 + dx = x2' 
-s * x2 + c * y2 + dy = y2'
```

solve it for unknown c, s, dx, dy (really c and s are not independent)